# mulitple where or conditions in Linq to object

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have a list of TelephoneDataType objects

```
 public List<TelephoneDataType> Values { get; set; }
```

The TelephoneDataType object has a enum property called ChartType

```
public class TelephoneDataType
{
  public ChartType ChartId { get; set; }
}
```

So from this Values List, I want to pull out all TelephoneDataType objects that has ChartId  set to any of the following values:

Answered
Abandoned
ExpectedWait
InQueue

Here is my failed attempt

```
var items = telephoneData.Values
                    .Where(c => c.ChartId == Enums.ChartType.Answered)
                    .Where(c => c.ChartId == Enums.ChartType.Abandoned)
                    .Where(c => c.ChartId == Enums.ChartType.ExpectedWait)
                    .Where(c => c.ChartId == Enums.ChartType.InQueue).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your current solution is doing `&&`'s between your `.Where` clauses.  You need to make them `||`'s by doing one of the following

```
var items = telephoneData.Values
                         .Where(c => c.ChartId == Enums.ChartType.Answered
                                  || c.ChartId == Enums.ChartType.Abandoned
                                  || c.ChartId == Enums.ChartType.ExpectedWait
                                  || c.ChartId == Enums.ChartType.InQueue
                               )
                         .ToArray();
```

or (which is more readable and easier to update/maintain)

```
  var myFilterList = new [] 
  {
      Enums.ChartType.Answered,
      Enums.ChartType.Abandoned,
      Enums.ChartType.ExpectedWait,
      Enums.ChartType.InQueue
  };

   var items = telephoneData.Values
                            .Where(c => myFilterList.Contains(c.ChartId)
                            .ToArray();
```

Also remember that your `.Where` clauses aren't executed immediately.
They are only executed when you do a `.ToList`, `.ToArray`, etc.
You can read more about that here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738633(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather implement an *extension method* for `Enums.ChartType` e.g.

```
  public static class EnumsChartTypeExtensions {
    //TODO: find out a proper name for the method
    public static Boolean IsOnLine(this Enums.ChartType value) { 
      return value == Enums.ChartType.Answered || 
             value == Enums.ChartType.Abandoned ||
             value == Enums.ChartType.ExpectedWait ||
             value == Enums.ChartType.InQueue; 
    }
  }
```

And so your Linq will be *far more readable*:

```
  var items = telephoneData.Values
    .Where(c => c.ChartId.IsOnLine())
    .ToArray();
```

Yet another advantage of the solution is if you add some statuses into `Enums.ChartType` (e.g. `WaitingForAnswer`) all you'll have to do is to update the *extension methods* only (and not all your Linq within the whole application)

Answer (score 0):

Think through your query step by step.  First you get all charts with ID `Answered`.  You then take that list and filter it for `Abandoned`, but the entries are all `Answered` already.

Try using the or operator.

```
var items = telephoneData.Values
                .Where(c => c.ChartId == Enums.ChartType.Answered ||
                            c.ChartId == Enums.ChartType.Abandoned ||
                            c.ChartId == Enums.ChartType.ExpectedWait ||
                            c.ChartId == Enums.ChartType.InQueue).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `Where` returns a filtered enumerable, so after your first `Where` you are only left with a single `ChartType`. You must combine the conditions into a single `Where` operation like this:

```
var items = (telephoneData.Values
                    .Where(c => c.ChartId == Enums.ChartType.Answered || c.ChartId == Enums.ChartType.Abandoned || c.ChartId == Enums.ChartType.ExpectedWait || c.ChartId == Enums.ChartType.InQueue)
                    .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the best way, which will help you not only in this situation - to write a special extension method for enums:

```
 public static class EnumExtensions
 {
        public static bool InSet<T>(this T target, params T[] possibleValues) where T : struct 
        {
            return possibleValues.Contains(target);
        }
    }
```

And solution is:

```
var items = telephoneData.Values
                .Where(c => c.ChartId.InSet(Enums.ChartType.Answered, 
                                            Enums.ChartType.Abandoned,
                                            etc...);
```